# Ruby on Rails deploy Capistrano sqlite db no schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, web-deployment, capistrano3

When trying to deploy Ruby on Rails application with Capistrano to Ubuntu 14 server, I've got an issue, the sqlite3 database file is always created, but no schema is loaded, the Capistrano deployment always fails. When I check the target database folder on the remote server, the *.sqlite3 database file is created, but it is absolutely empty. I've tried to add capistrano task to load schema, but it didn't solve the problem.

```
  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute 'cd #{current_path}; rake db:schema:load'
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end
```

Also I noticed locally, that when calling `rake db:setup` the database **schema is NOT loaded**, I have to call manually `rake db:schema:load` to run application locally, but how I can do it in the scope of Capistrano deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Capistrano, initial setup of the database is manual.

Here is the ticket discussing options for fixing this: https://github.com/capistrano/rails/issues/118

Comment: even though, I have another Ruby on Rails application, which is using sqlite adapter in production. There must be some configuration or something to keep the same production.sqlite3 database file during each Capistrano deployment. I think, that the solution is to navigate into **current** deployment folder and run `$ rake db:create db:schema:load` from there. So during the next Capistrano deployment, the database file 'won't be replaced. But I've already configured Postgresql, it's simple for staging and production server than sqlite.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is to add the sqlite dir to linked_dirs. That will keep the sqlite files across deploys. But I agree that using postgres or mysql is usually a better option for prod.